# Javascript Dynamic Event Assignment acting strange

Tags: javascript, events

I am having problems with Javascript event handler functions created dynamically.

In my HTML I have the following:

```
<input id="nvctrlfont1" type=number min=18 max=144 step=1 value=36 maxlength="3" size="8">
<input id="nvctrlfont2" class="color" value="000000" style="background-color:black;width:70px;">
<input id="nvctrlfont4" class="color" value="000000" style="background-color:black;width:70px;">
```

.....

The class color is just a javascript color picker.

The element ID's have 1,2,4 ... etc as Boolean values.  That is to say a JS function receives a Boolean that is used to hide or display the HTML input elements. For elements that are hidden no events are to be assigned, for those that are not hidden, events are to be assigned.

The Events functions would reside in the nvFontFuncs.

The problem I cannot seem to solve:

When the function assignment takes place to the nvEL.onchange it appears to replace it each time with the same function.

For example, given the Boolean nvFontBool comes in with say "6" then what should happen is the Input Elements nvcontrolfont2 and nvcontrolfont4 should be enabled and have the functions in nvFontFuncs nvctrlfont2 and 4 respective be assigned to the onchange events accordingly.

What happens however is nvctrlfont4 function ends up getting assigned to BOTH elements.

In other words, no matter which element that has had its onchange event set, when clicked it calls the LAST one assigned.  In my example, nvctrlfont4() gets called no matter if I change INPUT nvctrlfont2 or nvctrlfont4 elements.

If I for example change the nvFontBool parameter to "7" thus enabling all three input elements.  Then no matter which one is changed, it calls nvctrlfont4() (which happens to be the last one assigned in the loop).

I tried using addEvent and setAttributes as well, same results.  Its as the onchange assignment of the function is static when bound.  So which ever is the most "recent" one bound ends up replacing the prior bindings across all elements respective.

Help?

Heres the JS.

```
var nvFontFuncs = {
  nvctrlfont1: function () { alert('Function 1'); },
  nvctrlfont2: function () { alert('Function 2'); },
  nvctrlfont4: function () { alert('Function 4'); }
};
```

Here is the Function

```
function nvSetFontCtrls(nvFontBool)
{
    var nvEL;
    var nvName="nvctrlfont";
    var nvTemp;

    nvFg=1;
    while(nvFontBool != 0) {
        //alert("FontBool:"+nvFontBool);
        nvTemp=nvName+nvFg.toString();
       // nvTemp="func"+nvFg.toString(); 
        nvEL=document.getElementById(nvTemp);
        if(nvFontBool & nvFg) {
             nvEL.style.display="block";
             nvEL.onchange=function() { nvFontFuncs[nvTemp](); }
        }
        else {
            nvEL.style.display="none";        
        }
        nvFontBool=nvFontBool&(~nvFg); //alert("nvfontbool:"+dechex(~nvFg));
        nvFg = nvFg << 1; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign the following function:

```
function() { nvFontFuncs[nvTemp](); }
```

`nvTemp` is a variable in the local scope of `nvSetFontCtrls`. So when the handler is called, then, of course, nvTemp has the last value that it was set to.

You could do somthing like this:

```
nvEL.onchange=(function(nvTemp) {
  return function() { nvFontFuncs[nvTemp](); }
}(nvTemp));
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks so much! Apparently its a closure matter.  I am familiar with C++, VB, PHP and still getting the hang of javascript.  I was not aware of the closure matters, but, makes sense. Sorta!  Thanks again!  Thought I was going mad!

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah, closures can be tricky at first. But trust me, you will love them eventually ;)

Comment: Hi Again...  Question.  What if the function to be called by the event is not in the Font Functions Array?  Aka: A function elsewhere say that is also defined by the nvTemp variable. aka: nvTemp="nvSpecial" but nvSpecial does not sit in a function list. It is defined elsewhere. If I put the function name "nvSpecial();" in the onChange assignment.  Works fine.  If however I put nvTemp which is assigned the string "nvSpecial" it fails. nvTemp="nvSpecial" ....  onchange=function() { nvTemp(); } fails, yet, onchange=function() { nvSpecial(); } works fine.

Comment: In this case `nvTemp` is a string, so `nvTemp()` would be the same as `"nvSpecial"()` - you cannot call a string. If `nvSpecial` is defined in the global context you can call `window[nvTemp]()`.

Comment: ahhh... Gotcha. Stupid of me. In the first case nvTemp is used as an associative index, not in the second case.  I'd read someplace that "()" tells JS to handle a variable as a function. I am accustomed to C++ and VB mostly which are both strongly typed languages. Both PHP and JS are loosely typed. The quite wide open nature of what one can do in JS and even where in code is problematic for me being so accustomed to the implicit guardrails of C++ and VB.

Comment: That's right, `()` tells JavaScript to call the function that is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that nvTemp is set to the last value of the loop, so once the handler function was called, nvTemp will have 'nvctrlfont4'.

If you use `nvEL.onchange=nvFontFuncs[nvTemp]` assignment, the problem will be solved